# Как извлечь текст между скобками?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть текст: `(Hello)(world)...`

Мне нужно получить текст в скобках и вывести его в консоль. Но проблема в том, что неизвестно, сколько будет таких скобок.

Comment: Приведите пример входных и выходных данных. Приведите пример, как вы пытались решить задачу и какая именно проблема появилась. Могут ли встречаться конструкции вида `(word(word)word)`(со вложенными скобками) или `(word(word)` (с непарными скобками) и если могут, то какой результат должен получиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str1 = "(Hello)(world)";

string[] strs = str1.Split(new[] { '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string str in strs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно вытащить регуляркой `(?<=\().+?(?=\))`

Answer (score 0):

1.Вводим переменную,чтобы типа string (далее str)чтобы помнить текущее слово.

2.Запускаем цикл для поиска "(" открывающей скобки

3.Считываем символы в строку из нашего текста str+= наш символ

4.Условие выхода из цикла - нахождение ")" символа (str += " " чтобы между словами был пробел)

5.Возвращаемся в пункт 2

6.Печатаем str

PS не забыть в пункте 2 поставить условие выхода из цикла вообще == нахождение "\0" символа конца строки